# Sections not displaying in email template

Tags: html, css, html-table, html-email, mailchimp

I have no idea what's going on. The sections show up in preview and test emails, but when I add template to a campaign, suddenly the Contact and Facebook section is gone. WHYYY. It makes no sense why it's just disappearing when I add it to a campaign. This is the section that disappears when I add email template to the campaign. Is something wrong with the tables? I looked at CSS and there's hardly anything.

```html
    <!-- Facebook Recommendation -->
                    <div mc:repeatable="Select" mc:variant="facebook recommendation">
                      <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#231C15">
                        <tr>
                          <td valign="top" align="center" class="p30-15" style="padding:60px 0px 60px 0px;">
                            <table width="650" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="mobile-shell">
                              <tr>
                                <td class="td" style="width:100%;font-size:0pt;line-height:0pt;padding:0;margin:0;font-weight:normal;">
                                  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                    <tr>
                                      <th class="column" style="font-size:0pt;line-height:0pt;padding:0;margin:0;font-weight:normal;">
                                        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                          <tr>
                                            <td class="h3 pb20" style="color:#fff;font-family:Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:40px;line-height:40px;text-align:center;font-weight:bold;padding-bottom:20px;">
                                              <div mc:edit="text_16">Recommend us on Facebook!</div>
                                            </td>
                                          </tr>
                                          <tr>
                                            <td class="text pb20" style="color:#fff;font-family:Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:15px;line-height:30px;text-align:center;padding-bottom:20px;">
                                              <div mc:edit="text_18">Recommend us on our Facebook page! This ensures we can reach even more people to provide the best possible care during their move! </div>
                                            </td>
                                          </tr>
                                          <!-- Button -->
                                          <tr mc:hideable>
                                            <td align="center">
                                              <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                                <tr>
                                                  <td class="text-button" style="background:#fff;color:#231C15;font-family:Lato, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:18px;padding:12px 20px;text-align:center;letter-spacing:1px;font-weight:600;text-transform:uppercase;border-radius:22px;">
                                                    <div mc:edit="text_19">
                                                      <a href="https://www.facebook.com/pg/Moveoxforduniversity/reviews/" target="_blank" class="link-white" style="color:#ffffff;text-decoration:none;"><span class="link-white" style="color:#231C15; text-decoration:none;">RECOMMEND US</span></a>
                                                    </div>
                                                  </td>
                                                </tr>
                                              </table>
                                            </td>
                                          </tr>
                                          <!-- END Button -->
                                        </table>
                                      </th>
                                    </tr>
                                  </table>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                            </table>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Facebook Recommendation -->
                    <!-- Contact -->
                    <div mc:repeatable="Select" mc:variant="Contact">
                      <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#f4f4f4">
                        <tr>
                          <td valign="top" align="center" class="p30-15" style="padding:30px 0px 0px 0px;">
                            <table width="650" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="mobile-shell">
                              <tr>
                                <td class="td" style="width:100%;font-size:0pt;line-height:0pt;padding:0;margin:0;font-weight:normal;">
                                  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                    <tr>
                                      <td class="h3 center pb15" style="color:#000000;font-family:Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:24px;line-height:32px;font-weight:bold;text-align:center;padding-bottom:10px;">
                                        <div mc:edit="text_37">Contact Us</div>
                                      </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                      <td class="text-center pb30" style="color:#777777;font-family:Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:15px;line-height:30px;text-align:center;padding-bottom:20px;">
                                        <div mc:edit="text_38">Looking to make another move? <br>Give us a call!</div>
                                      </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                      <td align="center" style="padding-bottom:50px;">
                                        <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                          <tr>
                                            <th class="column-top" style="font-size:0pt;line-height:0pt;padding:0;margin:0;font-weight:normal;vertical-align:top;">
                                              <table class="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="text-align:center;">
                                                <tr>
                                                  <td class="img" width="50" style="font-size:0pt;line-height:0pt;text-align:left;"><img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/0d9e3bf61406dcc2f6b321e6d/images/1a994bda-97c5-4ebf-b478-de1e3e2e6d6c.png" width="34" height="34" style="max-width:34px;" border="0" alt="" mc:edit="image_20">
                                                  </td>
                                                  <td class="text" style="color:#777777;font-family:Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:16px;line-height:30px;text-align:left;">
                                                    <div mc:edit="text_39">
                                                      <a href="tel:8556244537" target="_blank" class="link" style="color:#777777;text-decoration:none;"><strong class="link" style="color:#777777;text-decoration:none;">855-624-4537</strong></a>
                                                    </div>
                                                  </td>
                                                </tr>
                                              </table>
                                            </th>
                                            <th class="column-empty2" width="30" style="font-size:0pt;line-height:0pt;padding:0;margin:0;font-weight:normal;vertical-align:top;"></th>
                                            <th class="column-top" style="font-size:0pt;line-height:0pt;padding:0;margin:0;font-weight:normal;vertical-align:top;">
                                              <table class="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="text-align:center;">
                                                <tr>
                                                  <td class="img" width="50" style="font-size:0pt;line-height:0pt;text-align:left;"><img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/0d9e3bf61406dcc2f6b321e6d/images/9e146158-5e5d-4d4d-a99e-02f32506799a.png" width="34" height="34" style="max-width:34px;" border="0" alt="" mc:edit="image_21">
                                                  </td>
                                                  <td class="text" style="color:#777777;font-family:Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:16px;line-height:30px;text-align:left;">
                                                    <div mc:edit="text_40">
                                                      <a target="mailto:service@moveandstore.com" class="link" style="color:#777777;text-decoration:none;"><strong class="link" style="color:#777777;text-decoration:none;">service@moveandstore.com</strong></a>
                                                    </div>
                                                  </td>
                                                </tr>
                                              </table>
                                            </th>
                                          </tr>
                                        </table>
                                      </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                      <td>
                                        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" dir="rtl" style="direction:rtl;">
                                          <tr>
                                            <th class="column" dir="ltr" width="433" style="font-size:0pt;line-height:0pt;padding:0;margin:0;font-weight:normal;">
                                            </th>
                                            <th class="column-empty" dir="ltr" width="40" style="font-size:0pt;line-height:0pt;padding:0;margin:0;font-weight:normal;vertical-align:top;"></th>
                                            <th class="column" dir="ltr" style="font-size:0pt;line-height:0pt;padding:0;margin:0;font-weight:normal;">
                                            </th>
                                          </tr>
                                        </table>
                                      </td>
                                    </tr>
                                  </table>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                            </table>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                    </div>
                    <!-- END Contact -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay - From my limited knowledge with MailChimp I think I have stumbled across something.
I see in your table you have the `mc:repeatable="Select"` attribute. From the MailChimp help section - this says that this will be hidden automatically unless a user adds it via the campaign builder.

> Add the mc:repeatable attribute to any area that includes an mc:edit attribute to create a content block that can be repeatedly added to a template. Repeatable content areas are hidden by default so they only appear in a template if you add them within the Campaign Builder.

Source: [Mailchimp help (create editable content areas with mailchimps template language)](https://mailchimp.com/help/create-editable-content-areas-with-mailchimps-template-language/)